# C# async file operations / eliminate UI Blocking

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asynchronous

Maybe I'm just looking at this wrong, I don't normally have to write a UI with progress.  I'm trying to do this in a WPF app with .Net 7.0.  My code looks something like:

```
public async void ProcessAllFiles()
{
    var fileItemCollection = await GetFilesToProcess(@"\\MyServer\Share");
    foreach (var fileItem in fileItemCollection) 
    {
        var result = await ProcessFile(fileItem);
        PublishResultsToUI(result); 
    }
}

public async Task<ResultInfo> ProcessFile(FileInfo item)
{
    var result = new ResultInfo();
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // add processing results to result object
        ....
    ));
    return result;
}
```

The "GetFilesToProcess" locks the UI 10-15 seconds and each "ProcessFiles" locks the UI a second or 2 for each file.

The timing seems to be about the same with or without the async/await/`Task<T>` statements.

If the UI didn't freeze every few seconds all would be good.

Any ideas would be appreciated (I've read through a bunch of docs, and I just have not found ones that make sense to me).

Comment: Can you please show `GetFilesToProcess` implementation? And full `ProcessFile` implementation would help also. Is there any particular reason you are not returning `result` from task itself?

Comment: Please try to avoid `async void` unless it is an async event handler. Please prefer `async Task`